# RPC tooling not available for appengine connected android project for GPE 3.2?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, eclipse-juno, google-plugin-eclipse

I've created a sample appengine connected android project. But,I cannot find **RPC services**, under **Google drop down** like shown in this [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7SxNNC429U) at 15:43.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality has been removed in GPE 3.0. Sorry about the abrupt removal of it; RequestFactory is not the recommended way to communicate between a client and an App Engine app. Use Cloud Endpoints instead:

https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/cloud_endpoints

We haven't added support for GWT client libraries for Cloud Endpoints, but we will in a future release.

Comment: Ok, but for those who used GWT RPC + App engine, we should change our whole client-server communication ? If not, where can we find some documentation for integrating Android and App engine ?